# Integrate Autoit Scripts with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, autoit, selenium-webdriver

Could any one guide how to integrate an Auto IT script with in selenium web driver?

I am using a applet window embedded with in browser.
So, using Auto IT for keystroke & Mouse action.

I don't want to run the Auto It script as an `.exe` file in selenium.

I just want to covert the script in to selenium and run for future enhancement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution: AutoITx.jar. import the jar in selenium and directly use the autoit script in selenium web driver.